# what does "I'm so done!" mean

Tags: american-english, british-english

I want to know how to translate properly the sentence : "I'm so done !"

Context is a man telling a joke to a woman, walking in the street. As a react, she says that, even if she hasn't met him before.

(My native language is Spanish.)

Comment: Can you post the whole joke? It would be helpful.

Comment: Sharing the whole joke might help. From what you shared it seems the point is to say something along the lines of "I can't take any more." Or perhaps "I've had enough" with the implication that whatever is being referred to is unpleasant or unwanted and the person is no longer going to endure or accept it.

Comment: "I'm *so* X!" is a common idiom in the US, at least for those of a certain age.  "I'm *so* over him!" means that the speaker has (she claims) completely eliminated "him" as a romantic interest.  "I'm so fed up!" simply means that you have had enough of an annoying situation.  Basically, "so", in this context, is just a bit of emphasis.  "I'm so done!" might be used in several different contexts, with somewhat different meanings, however.

Comment: The joke is that the boy first asks the number to the girl as if he were single, but then appears his girlfriend and gives him a kiss. then she goes with him.
He returns and tells her that it is a hidden camera.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of [**aposiopesis**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aposiopesis):

> Aposiopesis (/ˌæpəsaɪ.əˈpiːsɪs/; Classical Greek: ἀποσιώπησις, "becoming silent") is a figure of speech wherein a sentence is deliberately broken off and left unfinished, the ending to be supplied by the imagination, giving an impression of unwillingness or inability to continue. An example would be the threat "Get out, or else—!" This device often portrays its users as overcome with passion (fear, anger, excitement) or modesty.

The woman in your example is explaining that the joke is so offensive or funny that she doesn't have the words to explain how offensive or funny it is.

See also: [I can't even](http://www.slate.com/blogs/lexicon_valley/2014/03/12/language_i_can_t_even_is_just_the_newest_example_of_an_old_greek_rhetorical.html)